# Why does returning a HttpResponseMessage from an API controller action, using ASP.Net Core MVC 6 Api differ to Web Api 2 (ASP.Net, .Net framework)

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, c#-2.0

Ok so given the following  code for a Get action in a controller  :

`public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromRoute] int customerId)
{
  return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK); 
}`

In a controller hosted in a .NET Core  Asp.Net API we get this response in my client:

`{
    "version": {
        "major": 1,
        "minor": 1,
        "build": -1,
        "revision": -1,
        "majorRevision": -1,
        "minorRevision": -1
    },
    "content": null,
    "statusCode": 200,
    "reasonPhrase": "OK",
    "headers": [],
    "requestMessage": null,
    "isSuccessStatusCode": true
}`

For a controller hosted in a  Web api 2, api. .NET Framework (4.6.1) host we get this response:

There is no serialised body and exactly what I expect

`200 OK`

Comment: Are you suggesting you get different results when not using .NET Core? It would be good to show what happens there.

Comment: Fundamentally, that's what I'd expect though - did you only expect the properties you'd set directly to be set? If so, maybe you should manually just create an anonymous type with the properties you want. That version, for example, *is* the version stored in the Version property... how would the system know that you didn't want it serialized?

Comment: @daisy I am using Core atm, perhaps I might not get different results using .net framework. I think I was hoping a specfic convenience class or helper merhod may be available in  core. You may recall request.createresponse   previously.

Comment: I know there is a shim library for example but dont want to use that if I can help it.

Comment: @daisy shipton I dont know why Id expect everything serialised.  Perhaps Im getting confused with the name. Previously I have returned a HttpResponseMessage from Request.CreateResponse.  Im prolly misunderstanding its usage.

Comment: Part of the problem is that you haven't shown what you're *doing* with the response. If you want to convert an `HttpResponseMessage` into JSON, that JSON looks perfectly reasonable. If you're trying to return that *as the response itself* that's a different matter.

Comment: I am effectively trying to clone a response from another API and replay it . Retaining all of its characteristics.  Almost as is there was no intermediary.  There is reason for this which I wont go into,  But, really, I wanted to avoid copying across property by property etc. I have an approach anyhow,.  The crux of this is I dont understand HttpResponseMessage properly and how it is treated once it is returned from a controller action. This seems to be different elsewhere.

Comment: So you want the result served to the client to be the actual `HttpResponseMessage` you've created. Got it. If you could now provide a [mcve] of what you're doing, that would be great. Then we could try to work out why you're getting the serialized version.

Comment: @DaisyShipton  - Ok so I tested a Get action in a .NET core and .NET framework application.   There is a difference.  I shouldnt need to do an MCVe  as there should be enough to go on here (create a Web API project, add a controller, add the above code)

Comment: So the code is *exactly* the same in both ASP.NET Core and ASP.NET? (And can I check that that's what you mean by "in a .NET core and .NET framework application"? What happens if you run an ASP.NET Core application, but targeting the full .NET Framework? There's a big difference between .NET Core and ASP.NET Core, and it would help to know *exactly* what you're doing.)